# Not null attribute in Neo4J constraint

Tags: neo4j, constraints, cypher

It is possible to create constraint in Neo4J database for attribute to be not null?
 Something like:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: No currently this is not possible, this is the advantage and drawback of a schemaless dbms

Comment: However this is easily doable by writing a plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's planned and been already implemented for Neo4j 2.3, should be available with 2.3.RC1

Comment: I am using neo4j v3.But still I am not able to put not null constraint on any node's properties.