# user defined data integrity constraints in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, data-integrity

as I am relatively new to Neo4J and I was wondering if it is possible to impose user defined data integrity constraints on the stored data.

The manual says that it is possible to impose UNIQUE constraints and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439614/not-null-attribute-in-neo4j-constraint) Michael Hunger pointed out that in the current RC NOT NULL constraints have been added.

I was wondering if it is possible, in some way, to define constraints like "every node with label X has to have a relationship with Label Y" or to impose, in some way, a type system, possibly with a type hierarchy and everything.
Such constraints should automatically be checked by the DBMS, like in many of the old school (relational) database systems.

Cheers!

Comment: Take a look at @stefan-armbruster [UUID extension](https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-uuid) which registers a TransactionEventHandler that does som "enforcing", in this case that each node gets a UUID. It's a few years old but it's a very nice example to look at and learn from.

Comment: I will, many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have same functionality like traditional RDBMS has, at least not out of the box.

You can write your own [Unmanaged Extensions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) which could handle that for you. You can find basic information how to do that in this [article](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/transactions/2014/07/11/neo4j-transaction-event-api.html).

I'm not aware of any existing "plugin". In the future [GraphAware Enterprise](http://graphaware.com/enterprise/) should bring "schema enforcement".